# accessing files stored on server from Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, rackspace, vlad-deployer

I have a rackspace cloud server that I am hosting a Sinatra app on. I have a public directory in my app where I store my current styles, scripts, etc. I have additional files though that i dont want to be updating and transferring in with every deployment. I am using git and Vlad to deploy so to avoid this my current process is

- make local changes and updates
- update my local repo
- push to git
- run vlad:update
- then manually ssh into my server and mv the mp3s and other stuff I want in the project to the current releases' public folder

In short, I would like to be able to access files served in my user folder, or ideally also the option to access another user on the servers files with permissions, so that I don't need to always move them to the current release by hand.

thanks

Comment: Can't you just create symlinks with vlad from the app's public folder to the directories you need?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to serve the static files directly from Sinatra (i.e. you don't have Apache or Nginx set up to serve them) you might be able to use [`Rack::Static`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.3.5/lib/rack/static.rb). This will only work if the static files are all served from subdirectories of the other location. For example, if you have a bunch of mp3s stored in `/home/other_user/files/mp3s` and you access them like `http://example.com/mp3s/foo.mp3` then you could [use the middleware](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Rack%20Middleware) like this:

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/mp3s'], :root => '/home/other_user/files/mp3s'
```

If you have other subdirectories you want to serve files from, e.g. '/images', simply add them to the `:urls` array: `:urls => ['/mp3s', '/images']`.

If you want to be able to access the files at the 'base' of the url, like `http://example.com/foo.mp3`, then `Rack::Static` wont work. In this case we need to check each request against the directory, and if a matching file exists serve it otherwise continue on with the request. (Sinatra itself has to do something like this when checking its `public` directory).

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to use [`Rack::TryStatic`](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/try_static.rb) from rack-contrib:

```
require 'rack/contrib' #install rack-contrib first
use Rack::TryStatic, :urls => ['/'], :root => '/home/other_user/files/mp3s'
```

If you use either of these, you'll likely need to make sure you only configure the middleware in the right environment, otherwise you'll get errors in development when non-existent directories are looked for.